# How to implement replacement rule for products of variables?

Tags: replacement, algebraic-manipulation

If I have an expression in terms of multiplications of (pairs of) variables, e.g. $x_1$ ... $x_N$ such that the expression I want to manipulate is of the form

$A_{1,1}x_1^2+A_{1,2}x_1x_2+\ldots + A_{N,N-1}x_{N-1}x_N+A_{N,N}x_N^2$

What is the easiest way to implement the custom replacement rules

$x_ix_j\to C_{i,j}$

which can't be achieved with simple algebraic replacements for the individual $x_i$ (For instance $x_ix_j$ might represent the product of two random variables such that the replacement rules effect an expectation and thus give a correlation, i.e. $x_i^2\to \mathbb{E}[x_i^2]=\rho_i$ whilst $x_ix_j\to\mathbb{E}[x_ix_j]=0$, for example)?

Practically, I might have $x_1,\ldots,x_4$, say, but very large expressions that make manual substitution tedious.

Comment: If what you want for your actual project is an algorithm for Wick contractions of Gaussian variables there are answers for that here on stack exchange, one of which I use regularly.

Comment: If all of the $x_i$ random variables have the same distribution, you might want to consider getting familiar with `PowerSymmetricPolynomial`, `AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial`, `SymmetricPolynomial`, and `MomentConvert`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something like the following (?)

```
Sum[A[i, j] x[i] x[j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}] /. {x[i_] x[j_] -> 
   c[i, j], x[i_] x[i_] -> c[i, i]}
```

> [image: res]

Answer (score 4):

As a possibility, let:

```
expr = a[1, 1] x[1]^2 + a[1, 2] x[1] x[2] + a[2, 3] x[2] x[3]

rule = {Times[y__, x_[a_Integer] x_[b_Integer]] :> y C[a, b]
   , Times[y__, x_[a_Integer] x_[a_Integer]] :> y G[a, a]
    };
```

Test:

```
expr /. rule
```

> ```
> a[1, 2] C[1, 2] + a[2, 3] C[2, 3] + a[1, 1] G[1, 1]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this would work for you here, but this reminds me of similar cases where `Plus` and `Times` would give me headaches. An easy fix was to just replace as `expr /. Times -> times` (and/or `Plus` to `plus`), do whatever, and replace back when you're ready.

(I believe this is also the idea behind `Deactivate` and related functions, but they seemed slightly more finicky to me.)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. Here is your polynomial:

```
expr = Sum[
  Subscript[A, i, j]*Subscript[x, i]*Subscript[x, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 
   1, 5}]
```

[image]

Here is the replacement:

```
expr /. {Subscript[x, i_]*Subscript[x, j_] -> Subscript[c, i, 
   j], \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(i_\), \(2\)] -> 
\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(i, i\)]\)}
```

with the following effect

[image]

Have fun!